# External application - mouse click event within grid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pinvoke

I have an external windows application (no source code) that has a grid within it. This runs as a separate process. When the user selects a cell within the grid via mouse click, I need to be able to read the value within that cell. Can anyone provide some direction on what API's I would need to use to be able to trap and listen to the events?

Answer (score 1):

You best option is [UI Automation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) or accessibility as older technology.

Also you could take a look at this [Pinvoke SetFocus to a particular control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503027/pinvoke-setfocus-to-a-particular-control/9547099#9547099) on how to invoke things on another process (pretty much unrelated to automation, automation works w/o that)

UI Automation is the best tool for the job, **however**, the downside is that not every app supports that - so this very much depends on the app you're targeting. Some support only the legacy acessibility (IAccessible, IAccessible2 etc.), usually there is a 'combined' approach. Older techniques don't work very good any more but you could try traversing windows, child windows in the target window (for that direction you'll probably need the above technique sooner or later) and hoping you could get it from standard controls, windows text, via messages etc.