# Focsuing on Text box when the form opens

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Focus issue on Form Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388955/focus-issue-on-form-load)

I have a Activex control written in VB 6.0 or C++ maybe that been using it as a AxInterop in the C# WinForms program, it is very much like a text box but with some special logics, etc... and we have added it to a toolbar ... When the form loads I want the keyboard focus to be inside this so I used **.Focus** and also **.Select** methods on it but still it does NOT get the focus. When I run the program from VS IDE : It gets the focus. When I run the .EXE file outside of the IDE: It does not get the focus.

What do you think?

here is an screen shot of it too:

[image]

Comment: You seem to have created an exact duplicate of this question. I have posted my answer there, so you can now delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the component is visible when you try to give it focus?

If you are trying to do the focussing in a [`Form.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event handler, try moving it to the [`Form.Shown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) handler instead, or perhaps [`Control.Enter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx).

The difference in behaviour could be down to a timing issue.
Have a look [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx) for the order in which events occur on an opening form for more ideas.

Comment: great things to consider...will do

Comment: hmm where is "FormShown" event? can't find it..I could find "Enter" tho...

Comment: I updated the names for each event. To see a list of all events for a Form/Control, have a look at the Events list in the Properties window of the Designer. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984320(v=VS.71).aspx