# Send Key Press Messages To A x,y position

Tags: vb.net

I have explored sendkeys and wm messages however I am perplexed. Sendkeys only sends keys to an active window, not a specific region. I have an application I want to send key presses to, but only in particular locations. For example, the app has 4 sections, I want to copy all the text (using ctrl+a) from section 2 at 2350,185. But if I send the keys ctrl+a to the app, it trys to copy all sections, or the last section it was in. How can i send ctrl+a to the coordinates 2350,185?

Comment: That makes no sense, a keyboard message doesn't have a position associated with it.  Only mouse messages have that.  You'll send to the window that's in the foreground and has the focus.  That being the wrong window is a very common issue.

Comment: If i click the window (the whole app) and press ctrl a it does what send keys does. If i click in section 2 and press control a, it copies section 2. How do i set the cursor position (i guess) in the app then press ctrl a?

Comment: what in the world is section 2?

Comment: Call .Focus on the control you want the cursor to be in before sending the keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to have focus set to a specific control before sending keys to the application.  You can set the input focus to a particular control by calling `.Focus` on the control before calling `SendKeys`

If the control is in a different application you will have to resort to API calls using P/Invoke and basically send the windows message to the correct control to set the focus.  This  is not a simple task.

Comment: Check this link for an example of setting focus in a different application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503027/pinvoke-setfocus-to-a-particular-control